# NFA for a set of strings starting and ending with the same binary digit

Tags: regex, state-machine, nfa

So far, I have the regular expression 1(0|1)*1|0(0|1)*0. I am wondering if 0 or 1 by themselves count as an end state as they are single digits but do they technically start and end with the same digit?

Comment: yes they should be in this language.

Comment: what about an empty input - it will have no digits, but would it count as well, as it kind of starts with nothing and ends with nothing?

Comment: but nothing is not in the alphabet of the language

Comment: ok, I am not sure then how the regex would look like for this problem, if it was starting with 0/1 and ending with 0/1 it would have been: 1(0|1)*1|0(0|1)*0, but what would the regex be if we can accept only single digits as well?

Comment: Simple: `1(0|1)*1|0(0|1)*0|0|1`